# Strange error in Git-TF

Tags: git, version-control, tfs, git-tf

I'm trying to pull changes from Git into TFS. Getting this error:

```
git-tf: User config file C:\Users\Administrator.gitconfig invalid   
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.ConfigInvalidException: Cannot read file
C:\Users\Administrator.gitconfig
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to [this discussion](http://gittf.codeplex.com/discussions/393895), it could be related to an encoding issue:

> Problem was in config file encoding.
>   Proper one is ANSI & EOL = Unix

Comment: EOL = Unix is not necessary, but changing encoding to ANSI (was UTF8) solved the problem